# jCheckbox to be displayed in textarea

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I'm experimenting with JCheckBox. What I want is, when I'd check any of them(checkboxes), the text in the checkbox should be displayed in jtextarea.

What I have right now is this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CheckboxSample extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    //vars
    JCheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4, cb5, cb6;
    JTextArea ta;
    String text = "";
    JLabel lbl;

    CheckboxSample(){

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        c.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

        ta = new JTextArea( 10, 20 );

        //create two check boxes
        cb1 = new JCheckBox( "Java" );
        cb2 = new JCheckBox( "C#" );
        cb3 = new JCheckBox( "VB.Net" );
        cb4 = new JCheckBox( "Python" );
        cb5 = new JCheckBox( "C++" );
        cb6 = new JCheckBox( "Objective-C" );

        lbl = new JLabel( "Choose your favorite programming language/s: " );

        //add the checkboxes,  textarea to the container
        lbl.setForeground(Color.white);
        c.add( lbl );
        c.add( cb1 );
        c.add( cb2 );
        c.add( cb3 );
        c.add( cb4 );
        c.add( cb5 );
        c.add( cb6 );
        c.add( ta );
        ta.enable(false);

        //add action listeners. We need not add listener to text area
        //since the user clicks on the checkboxes or radio buttons only
        cb1.addActionListener(this);
        cb2.addActionListener(this); 
        cb3.addActionListener(this);
        cb4.addActionListener(this);
        cb5.addActionListener(this);
        cb6.addActionListener(this);

        //close the frame upon clicking
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //know which components are selected by user
        if( cb1.getModel().isSelected() ) text+="\nJava";
        if( cb2.getModel().isSelected() ) text+="\nC#";     
        if( cb3.getModel().isSelected() ) text+="\nVB.Net";
        if( cb4.getModel().isSelected() ) text+="\nPython";
        if( cb5.getModel().isSelected() ) text+="\nC++";
        if( cb6.getModel().isSelected() ) text+="\nObjective-C";
        //else text+="\nFemale";
        //display the selected message in text area
        ta.setText(text);

        //reset the message to empty string
        text="";
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //create frame
        CheckboxSample cr = new CheckboxSample();
        cr.setTitle("My Samples");
        cr.setSize(500,400);
        cr.setVisible(true);
    }

    }
```

How can I do that without concatenating the text of my checkboxes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I'm reading this right:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() instanceof JCheckBox) {

        JCheckBox checkBox = (JCheckBox)e.getSource();
        String text = checkBox.getText();

        int pos = ta.getText().getLength()
        ta.insert(text, pos);

        // or, more simply

        ta.append(text);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add a `ChangeListener` to every `JCheckBox`. The `#stateChanged(ChangeEvent)` get called every time you klick the checkbox.

```
final JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox("cb Text");
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("initial text");
cb1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {        
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            if(cb1.isSelected()){
                //textArea.setText(b.getText()); //to get the text from CheckBox
                textArea.setText("your Text here");
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: +1 for `stateChanged()`. This can be made more general by using `e.getSource()`. The text area's `Document` can be examined for deletion.